# Vim - Delete til last occurrence of character in line

Tags: vim

I'm trying to figure out how to `dt` or `df` the last occurrence of a character in a string.

For example, let's say I have the following line:

`foo not.relevant.text.bar`

If I `f df.` I expectedly get `foo relevant.text.bar` but I would like to get `foo bar`. Using `f 3df.` is not an option as I don't know how many of that character will be in the string. Additionally, I may want to get `foo .bar` (`f 3dt.`), or if the line ends with a dot, I may want to get `foo .`. I want to always find the last one regardless of how many there are.

Is this possible without a regex? I suppose I could use a regex but I was hoping there was a simple vim command that I'm missing. I find myself trying to do something like this often.

Comment: do you always want to delete from the begging of the line? if so just to the end of the line a search backwards `$F.d0`

Comment: If I search backwards then I would have to find the first occurrence of the character in the string as I still want everything before the first space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use my [JumpToLastOccurrence plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3386). It provides `,f` / `,F` / `,t` / `,T` commands that do just that.

Comment: Here's the github mirror for VimPlug users: https://github.com/vim-scripts/JumpToLastOccurrence and https://github.com/vim-scripts/ingo-library and https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat
(dependencies)

Answer (score 12):

one way **without** using **regex**, **without** **counting** "dot" (could be other letters)... see if others have better way..

`foo[I]not.relevant.text.bar` (`[I] is cursor`)

you could try:

```
lmm$T.d`m
```

or in this format, may look better?

<kbd>l</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>`</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>

this will do the job. you could create a mapping if you use that often.

**EDIT**

I add a GIF animation to show it works. :)

**note**

I typed **`@=`** in normal mode after moving my cursor to the right starting point (by `f(space)`), to display the keys I pressed in command line.

[image]

Comment: have you tried that? I tried it but `m takes me to the begging of the line.

Comment: where was your cursor when you start typing `mm` ? it will bring you back there. I just tried, worked fine.

Comment: +1 because that's very clever. However, it doesn't work if the line ends with `.`

Comment: I was doing it wrong. 'm takes me to the begging of the line, `m goes to the same column also.

Comment: @F.C. see my "test" in EDIT it is back-tick in my answer, *not* single quote.

Comment: @Rob, right, it is not perfect. :( but if the line ends with `.`, you see it right, just `D` will work. Well, sure, it would be nice if it could handle all situations. then we could write a function to handle different case depends on the character given by you. if it is really necessary. But on the other hand, if we go `writing function` that far, why not use regex??

Comment: Using just `D` would also delete the last character. In a situation where I wanted to use `f`, that would be fine. But I'm looking for a solution that works like both `f` and `t` because I may want to keep the last character I search for. I should probably update my question to provide a few more examples.

Comment: I said pressing `D` is for the case, which the line ends with "dot". in this case, the last ending "dot" is the last occurrence of "dot", so `D` works as you wanted.

Comment: So what if i have `foo not.relevant.text.` and want to get `foo .` Using `D` will just give me `foo` where as `f 3dt.` will give me `foo .`

Comment: @Kent - how'd you make the video?

Comment: @mcmlxxxvi my explanation won't be clearer than the vim help. any command you don't understand, just do `:h X`, e.g. `:h m`

Comment: well, "go one char to the right, leave a mark called *m*, go to line end, then to last period, delete back till mark" would *indeed* have been more helpful than `:h m :h T` (also `:h $` and `:h d` to see if there are any quirks). Especially since my problem is a little different from OP's, and after that I have to translate those normal-mode commands to vimscript.

Comment: @mcmlxxxvi if you are writing vimscript, you can do Normal mode commands for sure, like `$,t,f,F...` however there could be more possibilities do things in script way. From my point of view, checking help on my own is always better than someone telling me, this command just does A,B and C. I would check the help later anyway. Perhaps we prefer different learning ways.

Comment: To each their own - I find vim's docs terse and hard to read, especially when looking for concepts in an already quirky language (in my case, syntactic differences between normal mode and vimscript, e.g. escaping pipe characters).

Answer (score 4):

I would use `f df...`

It is not necessarily shorter to type, but I find it easier to use "repeat last command" than counting in advance the number of word/sentence I want to delete.

Then you can adjust the number of `.` you type to adjust the length of the string you want to delete.

Comment: This is pretty much what I've been doing all along and it's fine most of the time except when I want to use it in a macro.

Answer (score 1):

For your example: <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

> foo not.relevant.text.bar

And it works, as long as the cursor is anywhere within the text following "foo".

## Strip Path from Path+Filename: <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

I use it for stripping a pathname of all but the trailing filename.

> Strip the path from **/some/long/path/filename.ext** leaving only the filename.

Just as long as:

- The cursor is anywhere within the bold word
- There are no spaces in that word

  1. <kbd>E</kbd> Go to the end (since there are no spaces - also works if not the last thing on the line)
  2. <kbd>T</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> Find the last `/` (stop just after it, so it will be deleted, as well)
  3. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Delete to the beginning of the word

Answer (score 0):

In visual mode:

```
$F.d^
```

The $ goes to the end of the current line, F searches backward for a period and d^ deletes till the beginning of the line.

Comment: Oh sorry, this doesn't leave out the text before the cursor position when you start.

Comment: If it'll make you feel better: it helped me finding a way to just "jump to last occurrence" :) : `$F.` 