# Motion to last character

Tags: vim, motion

Is there a motion to move to the last of a character?

Example:

`[A]pple -> move to last p -> Ap[p]le`

I can do that with `2fp` but if there's lots of "p"s in the line then it's not so easy to count them then do `10fp`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim - Delete til last occurrence of character in line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249160/vim-delete-til-last-occurrence-of-character-in-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My [JumpToLastOccurrence plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3386) extends the built-in `f` / `F` / `t` / `T` motions with counterparts (by default bound to `,f` etc.) that move to the last occurrence of `{char}` in the line.

Answer (score 7):

```
$Fp
```

`$` jumps to the end of the line, `F` jumps backwards to the character `p`.

This does not work if `p` is your last character.

Comment: This isn't a motion, it won't work with an operator, i.e `d$Fp`

Comment: It's two motions, so if you wanted to delete backwards to the last "p" in the line, it would be $dFp.  Deleting everything before the last "p" would be $Fpd0, which you could use as a macro if you needed to repeat it.  I don't see a major advantage to having it in a single motion, but maybe someone can explain that to me.

Comment: With `$Fpd0` you can delete everything before the last character, but you cannot delete everything between the cursor and the last character. It would work with visual mode, though.

Answer (score 5):

### Search from the end

Instead of looking for the last occurrence of a character - move to the end and look backwards for the first:

```
$Fp
```

Comment: This isn't a motion, it won't work with an operator, i.e `d$Fp`

Comment: Sorry, as a motion you'll need [something like this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3386) afaik.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such motion.

But you could always do `vfp;;;;d` or `v$Fpd`.

Or find another more suitable target.

Or use a plugin like Easymotion.

Answer (score 1):

My Vim plugin [improved_ft](https://github.com/chrisbra/improvedft) also allows for this. Set `let g:ft_improved_multichars = 1`, press `f` and then type `p` followed by `l`.